# Why my Javascript animation doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to make a small animation to make a div(id="dice") grow in width, but I don't know what's going wrong. The position is already absolute. I have tried to create a button to test it (id="Pr_btn").

```
const pr_btn=document.getElementById("Pr_btn");
pr_btn.addEventListener("click", VtnDice);

function VtnDice(){
    let interv = null;
    const dice=document.getElementById("dice");
    let diceWidth=0;
    clearInterval(interv);
    interv=setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame(){
        if(diceWidth<300){
            clearInterval(interv);
        }else{
            diceWidth++;
            dice.style.width= diceWidth + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if(diceWidth<300)` will be true immediately. I suppose you intended `if(diceWidth>300)`. Basic debugging would have revealed this to you. Why not using a debugger?

Comment: Because visual studio code says "Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined". I have tried several solutions and nothing works, but I was angry not to see the error in something so simple a priori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple ! Your condition to stop the growth is the wrong way around :)
Replace `diceWidth<300` with `diceWidth>=300` and it should work like a charm !

I did a fiddle there : https://jsfiddle.net/4ubvm1a7/1/

Comment: Thank you!. I have looked everywhere but there.